# PowerShell task for AzureDevops not working under custom conditions

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am using Powershell task in my build pipeline. I want this task to Run under a condition i.e.  ***Even if a previous task has failed, even if the deployment was cancelled***.  But i am unable to select this option when ever i select this option it automatically gets reverted and default value comes in.

Can anyone please have a look at this issue. and let me know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: That`s really strange. On my own org, it works ... but on another org, I can't change the Control option of powershell script.

Comment: I had something like this happen on Server 2019, but seemed to correct itself on a page reload.  If you are on services seems like a product issue?  May be better to report it on developer community.  The way you can work around it most likely is to highlight the field and use the arrow key down to move between options.  Does that work?

Comment: Hi Ahmad Hassan, Any update on this, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check on another browser?
I`ve tested the following steps:

1. Create and save a small build with one PowerShell.
2. Try to edit Control option with Chrome - the build reverted my changes.
3. Try to edit Control option with IE or Edge - it works.

**Update:** You can use the keyboard arrows to switch between options in Chrome.